# Retrieve view in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, listener, onitemclicklistener

I have a fragment communicating with an activity. This fragment has several buttons, one of those is "play". I have set up an onClickListener for when I press the button and I´ve also passed an interface of the listener to the activity to handle the actions once the button is pressed.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header, container, false); 

    play = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onButtonPressed(v);
        }
    });


public interface OnButtonPressedListener {
    public void onButtonPressed(View v);
}
```

The problem is that, once on the activity, when I implement the interface of the listener, this receives the View "v" that I´ve passed when pressing the button. Then I try to compare that view that I´m receiving to the specific button that originated the call, just to make sure which button I´ve pressed since several buttons share the same interface. For some reason, this comparisson is not working properly, but the listener interface itself works perfectly. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong with this guys?
This is the listener interface on my activity:

```
@Override
public void onButtonPressed(View v) {

    HeaderFragment h= new HeaderFragment();
      if (v==h.play){
          Toast.makeText(this,"View SI",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         if (mediaPlayer!=null){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create different calls for different buttons in your `listener`

```
public ButtinsListener {
 void onPlayClicked()
 void onStop()
//etc
}
```

Then

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onPlayClicked();
        }
    });
```

== is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location. In your case View v and HeaderFragment's h.play are different objects, they are not the same. Also h.play is probably null because this fragment is not attached to the Activity and didn't instantiate any of it's views. Anyway use the method i showed above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will create different calls depending on the button pressed. I know that would solve the issue since I wouldn´t have to compare buttons anymore but anyway, do you know how to solve the issue when I compare the view with the fragment´s object?

Comment: Firstly it's not the way you should do it. I've showed you the right way, but if you still want to use only one listener you can compare view's ids.  if (v.getId()==R.id.play) { do your stuff }

Comment: I know, but I needed to retrieve the view of the fragment for other tasks in the future, that´s why I asked. I´ve used your answer to solve the problem, thanks!